# square D QO 240V AC @ 30 Amp, 2-pole circuit breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker

I am getting 1 volt across 2 poles of square D QOU 240V AC @ 30 Amp, 2-pole circuit breaker and 119/120 volts out of the individual lugs. What is wrong here?

Comment: The breaker is plugged into both feeds of the panel.

Comment: Are any OTHER 240V breakers working correctly? Odds are you've lost a phase. for instance, see https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/214186/18078

Comment: Are there other 2-pole breakers in the panel?  Do the appliances connected to those breakers, or to the breaker in question, function correctly?

Comment: Is it actually plugged into a QO panel? Or is this just a compatible breaker?

Comment: Could happen if someone misused a three-phase panel for a residential split-phase service.  Edit your post and add legible pictures of the panel including its spec sticker with the model number and feeder configuration.  If you're comfortable doing so safely, use your VOM to measure between the feed lugs/conductors (wear safety goggles).  Check your meter for information on the service.

Comment: Just realized you mention Square D `QOU` which is not a panel bus circuit breaker, but has lugs on both sides (line & load).  You must have connected both line lugs to the same phase by mistake.  Provide more details about your installation -- where is the feed to this breaker coming from, what is it for, etc.

Comment: @jeff wheeler I just looked that up also put it in an answer it’s about all that could provide that output.

Comment: And QOU is more likely to be used in a 3-phase context.  A photo of the panel buses could be helpful.

Comment: I yanked the main breaker, put dielectric on the connections and shoved it back in. There was crackling noise and when I checked where it was coming from it turns out that whoever originally installed the load center (some 50 years ago) placed a clamp that held in the bus bars(?) had placed it right where the main breaker plugged in. Because it wasn't seated right it must have been disconnecting intermittently. I pried the clamp out enough to let the breaker seat and everything is ok now (120 out of each side and 240 across the 30 amp CB.)

Comment: I want to thank everyone for their help. As it turns out the problem was something that no one could possibly anticipate. After checking across the main feeds coming into the box (120 volts each and 250 across), I thought maybe the main breaker wasn't seated properly or corrosion had built up.

Comment: The previous 2 comments are in reverse order. Sorry about that, I'm new at this and ran out of space in the first half of my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You mention Square D `QOU` which is not a panel bus circuit breaker.  The `QOU` parts have lugs on both sides (line & load).  You must have connected both line lugs to the same phase by mistake.

Check your feed configuration.  The problem must be there.

[image: QOU example breaker]